# How can I use either a while or for loop to replace part of a string that is within a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

My code is a basic hangman game. My problem is that my user input keeps coming out wonky and I'm pretty sure that it is because I am using loops wrong...

I've watched hours of videos and read so many previously asked questions... I've tried to just play with all the suggestions I've seen and while some worked like my current code it ultimately lead to another problem. I'm quite literally begging for help. If you look at my code you'll see that I explain everything to myself in excruciating detail when I actually understand what I'm doing.

```
#Word Puzzle Version 1
# Fill in the blank to guess the word. 
import random, time

def main(): 
    # display instructions
    filename = 'instructions.txt'
    mode = 'r'
    file=open(filename,mode)
    instructions=file.read()
    print(instructions) 

    # display what is to be guessed
    #import words file
    filename2 = 'words.txt'
    # Step 1  - Open the file
    infile = open(filename2,mode)
    # Step 2 - Read the file
    content = infile.read()
    # Step 3 - Strip the content of any leadning or trailing newline characters
    content = content.strip()
    # Step 4 - Additional clean up with splitlines function
    all_words = content.splitlines()

    # Randomly choose a word from list all_words
    #I want only 1 word to be guessed
    number_of_words = 1
    #A sample of 1 word from my cleaned up list of words
    word_list = random.sample(all_words,number_of_words)
    # Use choice function from random module to choose sample from word list
    answer = random.choice(word_list)


    #Display word to be guessed
    #Calculate the length of each word
    Length = len(answer)
    Underscores = (Length)*'_ '
    #Prompt user to solve the puzzle
    answer_so_far = 'The answer so far is '
   #print('The answer so far is '+'_ '*(Length))
    print(answer_so_far, Underscores)

    #Prompt the player to fill in the blanks
    Guess_a_letter = 'Guess a letter: '
    guess =input(Guess_a_letter)
    guess = guess.lower()

    #If players guess in word replace the underscore
    # Loop through the letters in the real word
    for i in (answer):
        if guess == i:
            #print(answer_so_far, end = ' ')
            print(guess, end = ' ')
        elif guess != i:
            print('_', end = ' ')


    #Check if players guess is in the word
    while guess:
        if guess in answer:
            print('\nGood job! You found the word '+(answer)+'.')
            break
        else:
            print(answer_so_far,Underscores)
            print('Not quite, the correct word was '+(answer)+'. Better luck next time.')
            break        

    #End of game
    #time.sleep(1.5)
    input('Press enter to end the game.')


main ()
```

The actual result is supposed to display as follows
when correct:

Instructions

The answer so far is _ _ _ _ _

Guess a letter: a

The answer so far is _ _ _ a _

Good job! You found (random word)!

Press enter to end the game.

when incorrect:

Instructions

The answer so far is _ _ _ _ _

Guess a letter: a

The answer so far is _ _ _ _ _

Not quite. the correct word was (random word). Better luck next time.

Press enter to end the game.

EDIT: for clarification of "wonky"
[image: incorrect output]

[image: incorrect output]

Comment: `mode = 'r'` -- somewhat pointless variable. Variables should *increase* readability, not detract from it.

Comment: What do you mean with "wonky"? What is actually happening?

Comment: HI leo. By wonky I mean that my answers area kept coming out in different lines. I will illustrate in an edited version of my question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop until all your letters are guessed. Meanwhile you break your loop after first letter. Your code should be like this:

```
# read file, select random answer
guessed = False
# display number of letters in answer as underscores
while not guessed:
    # get a letter from user input
    # show placeholders with all guessed letters
    if {some check - were all letters of answer guessed?}:
          guessed = True
input("Press Enter to exit")
```

Check may be like this: create some set, add every letter user tried to this set, and check whether `set(answer) in your_set`